# Any way possible to get DTS audio output with MediaElement?

Tags: c#, audio, win-universal-app, mediaelement

Ok, the title tells what I need. I just wonder that is there any way to get DTS-audio output in mp4 (mkv) video files using MediaElement? It's looks like that Microsoft doesn't want to support DTS (still...yet...forever) so I'm trying to find other solution to solve this problem. For example some code project / lib or any other way that my app can convert / get audio track to ac3 , or any other solution? Oh, and wishing that solution works with Universal Windows Apps.